# Weird behaviour with class fields when adding to a std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, undefined-behavior, push-back

I have found some very weird behaviour (on clang and GCC) in the following situation. I have a vector, `nodes`, with one element, an instance of class `Node`.
I then call a function on `nodes[0]` that adds a new `Node` to the vector.
When the new Node is added, the calling object's fields are reset! However, they seem to return to normal again once the function has finished.

I believe this is a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Node;
vector<Node> nodes;

struct Node{
    int X;
    void set(){
        X = 3;
        cout << "Before, X = " << X << endl;
        nodes.push_back(Node());
        cout << "After, X = " << X << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    nodes = vector<Node>();
    nodes.push_back(Node());

    nodes[0].set();
    cout << "Finally, X = " << nodes[0].X << endl;
}
```

Which outputs

```
Before, X = 3
After, X = 0
Finally, X = 3
```

Though you would expect X to remain unchanged by the process.

Other things I have tried:

- If I remove the line that adds a `Node` inside `set()`, then it outputs X = 3 every time.
- If I create a new `Node` and call it on that (`Node p = nodes[0]`) then the output is 3, 3, 3
- If I create a reference `Node` and call it on that (`Node &p = nodes[0]`) then the output is 3, 0, 0  (perhaps this one is because the reference is lost when the vector resizes?)

Is this undefined behaviour for some reason? Why?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back . If you were to have called `reserve(2)` on the vector before calling `set()` this would be defined behavior. But writing a function like `set` that requires the user to appropriately `reserve` enough size before calling it in order to avoid undefined behavior is bad design, so don't do it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.  In

```
void set(){
    X = 3;
    cout << "Before, X = " << X << endl;
    nodes.push_back(Node());
    cout << "After, X = " << X << endl;
}
```

The access to `X` is really `this->X` and `this` is a pointer to the member of the vector.  When you do `nodes.push_back(Node());` you add a new element to the vector and that process reallocates, which **invalidates all iterators, pointers and references** to elements in the vector.  That means

```
cout << "After, X = " << X << endl;
```

is using a `this` that is no longer valid.

Comment: Is calling the `push_back` already undefined behavior (since we are then in a member function with invalidated `this`) or does UB occur the first time we use the `this` pointer? Would it be possible to i.e. `return 42;`?

Comment: @n314159 `nodes` is independent from a `Node` instance so there is no UB in calling `push_back`.  The UB is using the invalid pointer afterwards.

Comment: @n314159 a good way to conceptualize this is to imagine a function `void set(Node* this)`, it is not undefined to pass it an invalid pointer, or to `free()` it in the function. I'm not sure but i imagine that even `((Node*) nullptr)->set()` is defined if you don't use `this` and the method is not virtual.

Comment: I don't think that `((Node *) nullptr)->set()` is ok, since this dereferences a null pointer (you see that kore clearly when writing it equivalently as `(*((Node *) nullptr)).set();`).

Comment: `.push_back()` *potentially* invalidates all pointers, references, and iterators. Was `.capacity() == .size()`? Yes, looks like it.

Answer (score 15):

```
nodes.push_back(Node());
```

will reallocate the vector, thus changing the address of `nodes[0]`, but `this` is not updated.
try replacing the `set` method with this code:

```
    void set(){
        X = 3;
        cout << "Before, X = " << X << endl;
        cout << "Before, this = " << this << endl;
        cout << "Before, &nodes[0] = " << &nodes[0] << endl;
        nodes.push_back(Node());
        cout << "After, X = " << X << endl;
        cout << "After, this = " << this << endl;
        cout << "After, &nodes[0] = " << &nodes[0] << endl;
    }
```

note how `&nodes[0]` is different after calling `push_back`.

`-fsanitize=address` will catch this, and even tell you on which line the memory was freed if you also compile with `-g`.